# Find the CDF of Z when Z=XY for a given joint PDF for X and Y

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, bivariate-distributions

The joint probability density function of random variables $ X$ and $ Y$ is given by
$$
f_{X,Y}(x, y) =
2(1-y) \quad \text{if} \quad 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1
$$
$$
f_{X,Y}(x, y) = 0 \quad \text{otherwise}
$$
Determine the probability distribution function of $Z = XY$.

I know that this is a duplicate but there is never a full explanation of how to evaluate the double integral required to solve this question, or if there is an easier way. My working so far:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^{\frac{z}{x}}2(1-y)dydx = \left(\frac{z^2}{x}+2z\ln(x)\right)|_0^1
$$
This is where I fail to continue, because of terms like $\ln(0)$. What do I do?
I expect an answer of $F_Z(z)=z^2−2z\ln(z)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259098/determine-the-pdf-of-z-xy-when-the-joint-pdf-of-x-and-y-is-given).
I know that $F_Z = 0$ at $z=0$ since that is a right way to define it, but regardless I am stuck with getting an equation for $F_Z(z)$.

Comment: Your integral is not correct, $x$ should vary between $z$ and $1.$

Comment: @GérardLetac thank you, but now it seems that I get a different answer for $F_Z(z) = z (-1 + z - 2 \ln(z))$

Comment: @GérardLetac the solution you propose has an $f_Z(z)$ which produces negative values, which should never happen for a PDF, so it is still incorrect...

Comment: @ripbozo You're forgetting the other integral that's shown in the accepted answer to the linked question in which $x$ varies from $0$ to $z$. Add that to your result and you get the same CDF.

Comment: Well, guys, I just provided an immediate explanation for the exploding integral and did not mean to solve the exercise.